Progressive matrix with circles in/around boxes
A friend showed me one of those pattern matrices, which I usually enjoy resolving. However, this this particular case, I can't seem to even understand the underlying logic.
I noticed that the inside circles seem to be positive and outside ones negative, which explains the number of them. However, there must be more to it because of the circles' positions. I tried visualizing a rotation of the circles, assuming there's multiple ones that may be superimposed creating the illusion of a single one.

Extra difficulty is imposed by the lack of alternatives to pick from. I fear that the absence of that information makes it perhaps impossible to find the specific solution but I hope that even without it, someone may be able to suggest a feasible pattern style to consider.

If you assign

 every circle inside the square -1 and every circle outside the square +1, then the sum of the first two figures in each row/column equal the number of circles in last figure. If the sum is positive then the circles are placed outside the square, if the sum is negative the circles are placed inside the square. For the last figure, you can see that it's just -2+2=0, so the correct answer is just a square with no circles.


That goes along how I was figuring. However, it seems that this logic doesn't take into account the placement of the circles, only interior/exterior location. I feel that there's more to it: if you compare the first row versus the first column, there's a different figure, which somehow depends on the differently located inner circles on second position. What do you think about it?

@KonradViltersten The placement is not consistent, no. But I think it's intentional just to confuse. Also, it makes sense that the missing figure has no circles, since if the missing figure contained a circle/circles you wouldn't be able to derive to an exact answer given that you weren't handed alternatives (more than one way of placing circles inside or outside the square).

That's an interesting thought. Let's wait for a day or two, in case some prodigy savant sees something that we might have forgotten to consider and then, pick an accepted answer. If you ask me, this kind of logical testing must not have those loose ends and arbitrary ambiguity. The test is assessing the logical capacity, not the creative and fuzzy maybe'ness. My mathematical brain disapproves.   :)
